# After Register in config/app.php ServiceProvider Class not found in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, package, service-provider

I'm trying to develop my first package but I already struggle trying to do so.
I've followed 2 tutorials and done everything exactly as described however I'm getting:

> Class "Dkul\Admin\AdminServiceProvider" not found.

I also check my config/app.php path are rights, and add composer, json in my custom package with the same namespace but getting not found error and In console give something like

> In ProviderRepository.php line 208: Class "Dkul\Admin\AdminServiceProvider" not found.

file structure
custompackage
Dkul
Admin/src/AdminServiceProvider

Main Composer.json
"Dkul\Admin\":"custompackage/Dkul/Admin/src"

Config/app.php
Dkul\Admin\AdminServiceProvider::class

[image: Custom Package Path]

[image: config/app.php]

[image: Main composer.json]

[image: Composer.json of Custom package]

[image: Error Image]

Comment: make sure the  ```namespaces``` are correct of a file

Comment: yes it is same as config/app.php file

Comment: I think better way to develop package in to make separate project and then set absolute path in composer.json: put version of your package to "@dev" and add new key "repositories": [ { "type": "path", "url": "../relative/path/to/repo" } ]

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel composer.json, autoload section you have set path without top folder "app". Please try:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            ...,
            "Dkul\\Admin\\": "app/custompackage/Dkul/Admin/src"
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thank You, After this change now my code works perfectly.